# error while sending mail without cc and bcc fields

Tags: php, sql-server

I am able to send and recieve mails in to, cc, bcc fields. But when I try to send mails only with the 'to' field filled in nothing happens.

I'm using the code below:

```
<?php
            $to= $_POST["too"];
            $cc= $_POST["ccc"];
            $bcc=$_POST["bc"];
            $strSubject = $_POST["subj"];
            $strMessage = $_POST["message"];
            $strHeader = "";
            $strHeader .= "Cc: ".$cc."\r\n";
            $strHeader .= "Bcc: ".$bcc."\r\n";
            $strHeader .= "from: xyz <xyx@mydomain.com>";
            $strHeader .= $strMessage."\n\n";
            $strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";
    }

    $flgSend = @mail($to,$strSubject,null,$strHeader);
?>
```

Comment: What error message do you recieve?

Comment: I am getting mail cannot be sent,except that no error,its not sending mail.

Comment: below is the code I used

Comment: $to= $_POST["too"];
$cc= $_POST["ccc"]; 
$bcc=$_POST["bc"];
$strSubject = $_POST["subj"];  
$strMessage = $_POST["message"];
$strHeader = "";  
$strHeader .= "Cc: ".$cc."\r\n";
$strHeader .= "Bcc: ".$bcc."\r\n";
$strHeader .= "from: xyz <xyx@mydomain.com>";
$strHeader .= $strMessage."\n\n";  
$strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";  
}  
  
$flgSend = @mail($to,$strSubject,null,$strHeader);

Comment: You're intentionally suppressing error messages, not that `mail` ever produces any that are worthwhile.  Just scrap everything and switch to PHPMailer or Swiftmailer.

Comment: Is it just me, or do you have a bracket in the middle of nowhere?

Comment: And also, just a hunch. It might be that you've misspelled "too". Maybe you've spelled it like "to" in the actual form?

Comment: Hello, everyone thanks for the response my problem is not with sending mail.I am able to send the mail when I filled all the fields:to,cc,bcc.But when I try to send mail with only to field and no recipient in cc and bcc,then I am getting error.Its not allowing me to left empty cc and bcc fields.You can go through below url:www.buzinessworld.com/test.php

Answer (score 1):

Modify the code to append the `Cc:` or `Bcc:` line only when the corresponding value has been provided.